# How to show a table from a SQL Server database by using SqlKata?

Tags: sqlkata

I am trying to show a table from a database in my SQL Server 2017 by using SqlKata.

I have browsed for some researches. Based from [one of the articles](https://medium.com/@ahmadmoussawi/announcing-sqlkata-an-elegant-sql-query-builder-for-c-3d13a9ff7a6f), I need to write this command `var books = db.Query("Books").Get();`

My question here is: Where do we put the command in a C# .NETCoreApp 1.1 target framework file? And how to run to display out the result?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cast class use

```
var books = db.Query("Books").Get<YouClass>();
```

But you dont have cast class -> use

```
var books = db.Query("Books").Get<dynamic>();
```

If you want logging execute query, write code startup.cs

```
var db = new QueryFactory(connection, new SqlServerCompiler());

// Log the compiled query to the console
db.Logger = compiled => {
    Console.WriteLine(compiled.ToString()); //NLog - GrayLog - API - DB - TextFile - more..
};
```

etc. https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/logging